# Invariant property in Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measruable set.

I proved that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} m(E\cap(E+t))=m(E)
\end{align*}

by applying Dominated Convergence theorem to $\chi_{E}(x)\chi_{E}(x-t) $.

I want to know that

> Let $E \subset [0,1]$ be a Lebesgue measurable set such that 
>   \begin{align*}
> m(E\cap(E+t))=(m(E))^2, \qquad \textrm{for all} \quad \vert t\vert\leq 1/2. 
> \end{align*}
>   What is $m(E)$?

By previous problem, there exists  $\delta >0$ such that $m(E\cap (E+t))=m(E)$ if $\vert t \vert <\delta$. Thus, in $\vert t \vert <\delta$, we get $m(E)=(m(E))^2$. I thought that $m(E)= 0$ or $1$. However, I couldn't choose whether $m(E)$ is 0 or 1..

Any help is appreciated..

Thank you!

Comment: Well, it is certainly true for $m E = 0$.

Comment: I presume that by stating "I couldn't find the exact value," you mean that you know that the measure is either 0 or 1, but not which of those two?

Comment: Since $m(E)=(m(E))^2$, I can get $m(E)=0$ or $1$. However, I don't know the exact value of m(E).

Comment: Both 0 and 1 are exact values.  I am trying to get you to clarify what you mean by "exact," since it is not entirely clear to me.  By exact, do you mean "which one of these two possibilities?"

Comment: Sorry about my question's ambiguity... I thought that if we find the contradiction when $m(E)=1$, then $m(E)$ must be 0.

Comment: However, we must consider $\vert t \vert >\delta$. I thought your example has some difference with my problem.

Comment: @UmbertoP. This is true, but doesn't tell the whole story here.  For example, if $E = [0,1]$ then we have $m(E) = m(E)^2$ (and therefore satisfies the conclusion), but fails to satisfy the hypotheses.  The question is better phrased as "Does there exist a set $E$ such that $m(E) = 1$ and $m(E \cap (E+t)) = 1$ for all $|t|<1/2$?

Comment: @UmbertoP: how can it be $1$ for any $t\gt0$ when the maximum measure of the intersection is $1-t$?

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I was trying to get the OP to clarify their question a bit more before handing them an answer.

Comment: @Xander Henderson. I thought about proof.. Could you check my proof? Suppose there exist a set $E$ such that $m(E)=1$ and $ m(E\cap (E+t)) =1$ for all $\vert t \vert \leq 1/2$. Then, $m((E+t)\cap [0,1])=1$ . Take $t=1/2$. Then, $ (E+t) \cap [0,1]$ must be contained in [1/2,1]. Thus, it is a contradiction. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu(E) =1$, then $\mu([0,1] \setminus E) =0$. Thus $\mu([0,1] \cap (E+t)) =1$ for all $|t|\leq 1/2$. Using translations invariance, we get $\mu(([0,1]+t) \cap E) =1$ for all $|t| \leq 1/2$.

Taking $t=1/2$ and $t=-1/2$, then $\mu([-1/2,1/2] \cap E) =1$ and $\mu([1/2,3/2] \cap E) =1$. Thus $\mu(E)  \geq 2$. A contradiction!

That's exactly your argument in the comments - as I see now.

Comment: I think that $\mu (([0,1]+t)\cap E)=1 $ is changed by $\mu (([0,1]-t)\cap E)=1 $. Right?? Anyway, I understand it !!  Thank you!

Comment: How does $\mu E = 1$ lead to $\mu([0,1] \setminus E) = 0$?

Comment: Since $\mu$ is measure, $\mu([0,1])=\mu(E \cap [0,1])+\mu(E^c \cap [0,1])$. Then, we get $\mu([0,1]\E)=0$.

Comment: How do you get $E \subset [0,1]$ a priori?

Comment: $E\subset [0,1]$ is assumption.

Comment: I have already changed "coordinates', i.e. replaced $-t$ by $t$. Sincce the statement is true for all $|t| \leq 1/2$, we can do this.

Comment: @w.sdka: My apologies, I missed that assumption entirely.